# How to use header to recyclerview in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application i want show some lists and for this i should use `RecyclerView`.

I get this lists from **server**, you can see sample of my `json` in bottom :

```
{ 
     result:[
            list1:{
            title:title1,
            data:[
            {
                id:1,
                name:name1_list1
            },
            {
                id:2,
                name:name1_list2
            },
            {
                id:3,
                name:name1_list3
            }
            ]
        },
            list2:{
            title:title2,
            data:[
            {
                id:2-1,
                name:name2_list1
            },
            {
                id:2-2,
                name:name2_list2
            }
            ]
        },
            list3:{
            title:title3,
            data:[
            {
                id:3-1,
                name:name3_list1
            },
            {
                id:3-2,
                name:name3_list2
            },
            {
                id:3-3,
                name:name3_list3
            },
            {
                id:3-4,
                name:name3_list4
            }
            ]
        }
]}
```

I want show data of **`title`** into `recyclerView` of **title**, and show data of **`data:[]`** in `recyclerView`.

How can i it? Thanks guys <3

Please help me

Comment: What you tried so far ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, can you help me?

Comment: Have you written any adapter class or made any layout?

Comment: @AyushKhare, i can write layout codes. but i don't know how can i get data from deference if lists and set into recyclerView

Comment: How are you trying to read this server response?

Comment: @AyushKhare, yes i can read data from server

Comment: Post your java code, no one will write the entire code for you

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to look into RecyclerView adapters.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

These are then pushed into the layout (which you create) think of the layout as a placeholder for the data, but you need to program the new data that comes into into the adapter.
A good tutorial to learn this is have a read on Binpress Guide to (link below)

https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156

I have recently just learned how to tie adapters to views, and put in views and this tutorial helped out a lot.

P.S word of advice you need to place code examples or direct questions on what you are trying to do, or show an attempt of trying it.